# Separating HashMap Output to .csv with Comma

Tags: java, csv, hashmap

In this program, I am exporting the data from a HashMap database to a .csv. The data written to the file is the key and the studentInformation, which is composed of the Name, Major, and GPA. The code outputs this to the .csv fine, however I want each value to be separated by commas so each value is in a different column of the spreadsheet. How would I implement the comma on each output from the database???? Thanks in advance.

```
      //Output the database to the file
      Map.Entry<Integer, Student> studentInformation = iterator.next();
      int key = studentInformation.getKey();
      bW.write("Student ID: " + key + (",") + studentInformation.getValue() + ("\n\n");
```

If I add + (",") after studentInformation.getValue(), it doesn't separate each value of studentInformation... Any ideas?

Comment: You need to either override the toString() method of Student to output the CSV format you need or create a function with a Student input and a String output that correctly formats the student information.

Comment: I don't know that I fully understand what you're recommending here. I'm piecing it together but still not having any luck. Time to hang it up for today!

Comment: @Daniel Bickler using `toString()` is not advised. `toString()` is for debugging purposes, not to have the string representation in a specific format as CSV. If the fields from Student to write in the CSV are not the same as those required for debugging purposes, we are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each field that you want in a CSV column has to be retrieved individually from the `Student` class.
For example :

```
  public static final String CSV_SEPARATOR  = ",";
  ...
  Map.Entry<Integer, Student> studentEntry = iterator.next();
  int key = studentEntry.getKey();
  Student student = studentEntry.getValue();
  String line = "Student ID: " + key + CSV_SEPARATOR + student.getName() 
  +  CSV_SEPARATOR  + student.getMajor() + System.lineSeparator();
  bW.write(line);
```

Use custom constant as `CSV_SEPARATOR` to not repeat "," and prefer 
   `System.lineSeparator()` to `\n\n` that is OS dependent.

At last why do you want to reinvent the wheel ?
Libraries as SuperCSV and OpenCSV do a very good job.
You should try one of them.

Comment: Thank you! - I ended up taking a different approach to the formatting anyway, but your recommendation would certainly suffice had I stayed with my original intentions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Create a formatter function that takes a `Student` and returns a String.  Then call this for each value in your map.

```
public static String formatCsv(Student s) {
  return s.getName() + ", " + s.getGrade() + ", " + s.getHeight();
}
```

Or you can use the Guava Joiner class

```
public static String formatCsv(Student s) {
  return Joiner.on(',').join(s.getName(), s.getGrade(), s.getHeight());
}
```